# What will the color of my image look like once printed?

Tags: color, color-profile

I'm working on a project in Photoshop in CMYK. I exported my rendered tif file in 2 image viewers and they don't look the same. Windows image viewer shows the same as in Photoshop but ACDSee shows different colors. I tried changing color profiles in ACDSee but it doesn't change anything after restarting the program and reloading the file. It still looks off.

I'm trying to understand why ACDSee is displaying the picture that way but in the end my only concern is how the file will look once printed and I really hope it will be like on the first two. How can I be sure of this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for *any* application to display CMYK color correctly, that application **must** support CMYK color profiles.

Nowhere on the ACDSee website is there *any* claim of CMYK support in the application. ACDSee appears to be an **RGB-only environment**.

A cursory web search appears to confirm this in ACDSee's own forums: https://forum.acdsee.com/forum/acdsee-pro/7942-acdsee-pro-8-dipslay-very-bad-cmyk-colors-for-psd-files

To this end, ACDSee is most probably *ignoring* any CMYK color profile. And ACDSee is **not** an application one should be using for designs destined for CMYK print production.